# What is the difference between TADOConnection, TFDConnection and TSQLConnection?

Tags: delphi, database-connection

I'm looking to make a database connection but I'm not sure what db connection to use.

I saw there are many different ones available. `TADOConnection`, `TFDConnection`, and `TSQLConnection`.

What are the differences between all of them? Are all of them the same?

I didn't try any of them as I'm not sure which one is the correct one to use for a database connection. I have a PostgreSQL and a Firebird database that I want to connect to.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for each of those classes? They're described pretty well in that documentation, and that should be your first resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TADOConnection`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection) is a part of the ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) library and is used to connect to databases using Microsoft's ADO technology.

[`TFDConnection`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDConnection) is a part of the FireDAC library and is used to connect to databases using Embarcadero's FireDAC technology.

[`TSQLConnection`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection) is a part of the dbExpress library to connect to databases.

---

In conclusion, the choice of the database connection component depends on the specific requirements of your project.

`TADOConnection` and `TSQLConnection` are old and shouldn't really be used for new projects though.

You should be using `TFDConnection` for new projects. `TFDConnection` will be perfect for PostgreSQL and Firebird.

Comment: Why should dbExpress (TSQLConnection) not be used for new projects? We use it, it has modern and fast drivers and I see nothing wrong with it. Your statement made me curious.